# Git commit multiple files

Tags: magit, git

When I go to commit my changes VC seems only allows me to commit one file at a time via `C-x v v`. Is there a way for VC to commit more than 1 file at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)VC With A Merging VCS`

If you open `vc-dir` with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> you can mark files with <kbd>m</kbd> -- or <kbd>M</kbd> to mark *all* files in a particular state -- and then <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> will act on all of those files.

For Git specifically, [Magit](https://magit.vc/) provides a nicer UI than VC.  If you use Git a lot, then definitely check it out -- it's well worth learning to use.